# Integration QuickBooks Permier 2013 desktop version with web apps (PHP)

Tags: quickbooks

Trying to implement QuickBooks Premier 2013 desktop version with our web app for ordering but having problem with authentication in web connector.  The latest error as follows:

---

20131004.14:06:29 UTC   : QWCReader.ParseQWC() : Contents of QWC file: -

InnerException:

### 20131004.14:06:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.ReadQWC(QWCReader QWC) : QBWC1048: QuickBooks Web Connector could not verify the web application server certificate.

Need help to resolve the issues and make a successful connection between two apps.

Comment: SO is not a freelancer site, don't advertise contract work here.

Answer (score 0):

**The Web Connector requires a valid, third-party signed SSL certificate.** It sounds like you don't have one.

Do you have a valid SSL certificate for the AppURL that's in the .QWC file?

What's the domain? What's the URL? What does the rest of your Web Connector log file look like?

Comment: Yes, do have the SSL certificate for the domain.

Comment: And the domain name is...? What's the URL? What's the .QWC file look like? If you want answers, you're going to need to provide a lot more detail.